# Evento onBlur con Jquery no funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

Buenas noches amigos vengo a ustedes con una pregunta tal vez un poco extraña.

Tengo un formulario Ajax.BeginForm con dos campos, un campo de correo electrónico y uno de password. Con un script manejo los eventos de esos campos y del form. Tengo el evento onBlur del campo de email pero no funciona correctamente ya que el campo debe tener el foco dos veces para poder ejecutar el evento onBlur. Revise mi codigo y aun no encuentro el error. Agradeceria sus comentarios amigos y gracias.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", OpcionesAjax, new { @class = "login-form", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", (string)ViewBag.returnUrl)
    @*@Html.TextBox("direccion", (string)ViewBag.returnUrl , htmlAttributes: new { id = "UrlReturn", @class = "hidden"})*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
        <button class="close" data-close="alert" type="button"></button>
        <span>Introduzca un Usuario y Password. </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label ">
                <div class="input-icon">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { id = "Email", @class = "form-control", required = true, autocomplete = "off" })
                    <label for="User">Usuario</label>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                <div class="input-icon">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id="Password", @class = "form-control", required = true, autocomplete = "off" })
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wait-animation">

    </div>
    <div class="row hidden" id="divContainerRoles">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RolesUser, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                <div class="input-icon">
                    @Html.DropDownList("RoleId", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "UserRol", @class = "form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", required = true, autocomplete = "off" })
                    <label for="UserRol" class="pull-left">Elija su Rol</label>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="login-transition">

    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn green btn-signin pull-right" id="btnLogin" value="Account" name="toolbox" disabled>Entrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

Este es mi script

```
$("#Email").blur(function () {

    var usuario = $('#Email').val();
    var password = $('#Password').val();
    var returnUrl = $('#UrlReturn').val();

    if (usuario != null) {
        $('#divContainerRoles').addClass("hidden");

        var Persona = {
            Email: usuario,
            Password: password,
            ListaRoles: "",
            RememberMe: false,
            RolesUser: [],
            RoleId: ""
        };

        var dataRoles = [];
        var succes = false;
        //var urlbaselog = "~/Account/";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlbaselog + "ListRolesForUser/",
            data: { Email: usuario, Password: password, returnUrl: returnUrl },
            datatype: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                dataRoles = data;
            }
        });

        var listRoles = document.getElementById("UserRol");

        if (dataRoles.length == 0 || dataRoles.length == null) {
            App.unblockUI(".login-transition");
            alertToastr('danger', 'El Usuario ingresado no esta registrado en el Sistema', '');
            return;

        } else if (dataRoles.length == 1) {
            for (i = (listRoles.length - 1) ; i >= 0; i--) {
                aBorrar = listRoles.options[i];
                aBorrar.parentNode.removeChild(aBorrar);
            }

            for (var x = 0; x < dataRoles.length; x++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = dataRoles[x].Id;
                option.text = dataRoles[x].RoleName;
                listRoles.add(option);
            }
            App.unblockUI(".login-transition");
            $("#btnLogin").removeAttr("disabled");

        } else if (dataRoles.length >= 2) {

            for (i = (listRoles.length - 1) ; i >= 0; i--) {
                aBorrar = listRoles.options[i];
                aBorrar.parentNode.removeChild(aBorrar);
            }

            for (var x = 0; x < dataRoles.length; x++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = dataRoles[x].Id;
                option.text = dataRoles[x].RoleName;
                listRoles.add(option);
            }

            App.unblockUI(".login-transition");
            $('#btnLogin').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#divContainerRoles').removeClass("hidden");
            alertToastr('success', 'Seleccione el Usuario para Iniciar Sesión', '', 10000);
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Solo por aclarar, el problema esta con el evento onBlur, el elemento Mail debe tener el foco dos veces para ejecutarse, lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: a que llamas "tener el foco dos veces" ? podrias poner un `console.log()` para ver si esta ingresando al evento y hasta que punto llega, quizas el `$.ajax` esta demorando en volver por eso no ves resultado hasta la segunda ejecucion. Recuerda que `$.ajax` es asincrono en su ejecucion

Comment: porque mezclas diferentes tecnicas de programacion, si venias usando jquery en el selector de los controles porque despues usas `getElementById()`. Ademas el codigo que usa la variable `dataRoles ` debes estar dentro del success, no por fuera. Nuevamente `$.ajax` es asincrono